UDP traffic between cloud and PC
I am trying to send UDP messages in both ways between my PC and server on cloud. TCP messages goes through no problem, but UDP...
From my laptop I can freely send packages to server and it is visible there. When server is sending back instant response it goes through and I can see it on my PC. This far all good. When I am trying to send UDP packages to my PC it does not go through. I cannot see the packages coming using Wireshark.
A little about why I am doing this.
I've created simple snake game and want to host it without need for using VPN service like Hamachi and ZeroTier. Using TCP is too slow and makes everything lagging at some point. I believe others are using UDP (big ones like League of Legends etc.) so it should be possible without setting any port forwarding manually on router. I want players to not do any extra preparation steps outside my game.
What I've already tried.
I've made all tests using example python asyncio datagram connections and netcat. I've tried sendind packages from my home network behind router and also through my mobile LTE network (using wifi hotspot).
I've tried hole punching (AFAIK also known as NAT hairpinning) - it works in my local network but not through cellular hotspot.
I've listened on port 5350 and 5351 to detect using PCP (Port Control Protocol) but it seems that is not used for example by youtube.
Just for the record, TCP connection initialized from PC side works just fine.
I am Fedora linux user without firewall (there is no blocking rules after using iptables -S).

It is not sufficiently clear from your question what you are doing (no code, no pcap, no graphics showing how data flow, ...). But, incoming UDP will not pass through a NAT router unless there is a matching(!!) outgoing UDP first because without this the NAT router does not know (has no matching state) which internal device the packet should be delivered to. And no, NAT hairpinning is not the same as hole punching.

What you mentioned is called hole punching and I've already tried it as mentioned (i checked hairpining, its different and i didn't tried it cause it is not for what i want to do)

I have no idea what you think hole punching is since you only mention that you've tried it, without going in the details. But the general understanding (see Wikipedia) is not the same as I tried to explain. Again, it is unfortunately not known what you are really doing.
